# R: empty lists inside list of lists after running function + for loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, loops

I have a list of dataframes which contain two columns with variables: var1 and var2. Several of the variables in var1 and var2 are NAs. Now, I want to create a new list of dataframes in which each dataframe contains only those rows that have no NA values in var1 OR var2.

This is the structure of my dataset:

```
df1 = data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 var1 = c(0.1, 0.24, 0.11, 0.8, NA),
                 var2 = c(1, NA, 0, NA, 1))
df2 = data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 var1 = c(NA, NA, 0.11, 0.8, 0.1),
                 var2 = c(100, 19, NA, 9, NA))
df3 = data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 var1 = c(0.12, 0.3, 0.5, NA, 0.84),
                 var2 = c(100, 19, 2, 9, 10))
df_list = list(df1, df2, df3)
```

This is what I wrote to accomplish my task (a for loop inside a function):

```
out = lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  dfList = list()
  for (i in c(2:3)) {
    df = x[complete.cases(x[ , i]),]
    dfList[[i]] = list(df)
  }
  return(dfList)
})
```

Now, this works but it is not optimal. The reason for that is that the output creates a list of lists in which some lists do not contain any values:

```
> out

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1 0.10    1
2  2 0.24   NA
3  3 0.11    0
4  4 0.80   NA


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1 0.10    1
3  3 0.11    0
5  5   NA    1



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
3  3 0.11   NA
4  4 0.80    9
5  5 0.10   NA


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1   NA  100
2  2   NA   19
4  4  0.8    9



[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
NULL

[[3]][[2]]
[[3]][[2]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1 0.12  100
2  2 0.30   19
3  3 0.50    2
5  5 0.84   10


[[3]][[3]]
[[3]][[3]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1 0.12  100
2  2 0.30   19
3  3 0.50    2
4  4   NA    9
5  5 0.84   10
```

I want to avoid those empty lists inside my output but did not manage to figure out the issue with my code. Any ideas?

Comment: is your output correct though?

Comment: Yes, the output dataframes are exactly what I need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is looping from 2, and then it got assigned, thus the `1` was left as empty

```
lapply(df_list, \(x) lapply(2:3, \(i)  list(x[complete.cases(x[[i]]),])))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1 0.10    1
2  2 0.24   NA
3  3 0.11    0
4  4 0.80   NA


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1 0.10    1
3  3 0.11    0
5  5   NA    1



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
3  3 0.11   NA
4  4 0.80    9
5  5 0.10   NA


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1   NA  100
2  2   NA   19
4  4  0.8    9



[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[[3]][[1]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1 0.12  100
2  2 0.30   19
3  3 0.50    2
5  5 0.84   10


[[3]][[2]]
[[3]][[2]][[1]]
  ID var1 var2
1  1 0.12  100
2  2 0.30   19
3  3 0.50    2
4  4   NA    9
5  5 0.84   10
```

NOTE: In the OP's code, `return` after `Filter`ing out the `NULL` elements

```
...
 return(Filter(Negate(is.null), dfList))
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully. Also great to see how I can adjust my own code to do what I want, although your first solution is definitely more elegant.

Comment: I have one more question. In above solutions, we are getting multiple levels in the dataframe names within the list. Even after running {unlist(out, recursive = FALSE)}, there are still multiple levels left in the dataframe names. How can this be avoided so that each dataframe has just one header? E.g., [[3]] instead of [[3]][[1]]. I feel the answer must be simple, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: @EAM91 Do you want `do.call("c", lapply(df_list, \(x) lapply(2:3, \(i) x[complete.cases(x[[i]]),])))`.  Your code is again nesting the output in a `list` with `list(` at the inner level.  If you don't want to flatten the outer list, just remove the `list(` in the code